# INSERT INTO query executes fine but can't be Saved as a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_00_TMP]
SELECT dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].CertId, 
dbo.   [800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Certificato, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].ALCertificato,  dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].DocNr, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].ALDocNr, dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Eti, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].ALeti, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Ordinamento, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].ValoreRpt, 
dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].TipoCert, 
SUM(ValoreRpt) OVER 
 (PARTITION BY dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Ordinamento) AS NrAllegato, 
 dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Analisi, 
 dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Ordinamento AS Ordina, 
 dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].CodiceRpt, 
 dbo.Certificati.CertRapporto, dbo.Etichette.Allegato, 
 dbo.[800_10_01_AltreLingue].ALAllegato


 FROM ((dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10] 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Certificati ON 
   dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].CertId = dbo.Certificati.CertId) 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Etichette   
   ON dbo.Certificati.CertCodLinguaCert = dbo.Etichette.idEti) 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.[800_10_01_AltreLingue] 
   ON dbo.Certificati.CertAltreLingue = 
     dbo.[800_10_01_AltreLingue].IdAltreLingue
 ORDER BY dbo.[800_00_Index_SM_00_10].Ordinamento;
```

This is the query I have. When I execute it it runs fine, But it gives the 
"Incorrect syntax near keyword 'INSERT'" when i try to save it as a view.

Comment: You can't use `INSERT` in a view..: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error because you can't create a view with `INSERT INTO` statement.

You have to `SELECT` the table you want a view from.

I assume you use MySQL so please check the syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: There's sql-server tag.